# HTML, CSS: Divs automatically jump into next row

Tags: html, css

as the title might suggest - for the most of you - this will be a beginners question: As shown in the image below, I want to insert *divs* with certain informations inside my parent-div. Whenever a new div would reach or rather cross the border of the parent, it has to move into the next row below!?

[image]

- the parent div has no absolute width
- the parent div will be scrollable on the y-axis
- the divs inside have an absolute width (350px)

My Question is: is this even possible? And what do I have to look for?

Thank you and have a great sunday!

Comment: You need `display: flex;` for the parent div

Comment: In addition to `flex`, please check out [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Comment: Are you trying to get the divs to be in one row, or do you want them to automatically wrap to the next line?

Comment: @yainspan I want them to wrap up into the next line

Comment: Are your divs to be of equal size as shown in your diagram or could they be any width and/or height?

Comment: @AHaworth they are all equal sized

Comment: @finethen does the form have defined width

Comment: @AnujaNimesh No, the form doesn't have a defined width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `flex` and `flex-wrap` for this:

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #cee;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Flex**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  width: 150px; /*350px*/
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #54D705;
  background-color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Content A</div>
  <div class="child">Content B</div>
  <div class="child">Content C</div>
  <div class="child">Content D</div>
  <div class="child">Content E</div>
</div>
```

**Grid**

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 150px);
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  height: 150px;
  border: 5px solid #54D705;
  background-color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Content A</div>
  <div class="child">Content B</div>
  <div class="child">Content C</div>
  <div class="child">Content D</div>
  <div class="child">Content E</div>
</div>
```